# Why is function being called before print function?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
print("The top 10 song for week 1 are",top_10_song(coll_w1))
```

Output:

```
List of 10 songs:
..
..
..
..
The top 10 song for week 1 are
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order for a print statement to print anything the [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) it is given as arguments must be evaluated to a printable value. In the same way that `x = 5` is equivalent to `x = 2 + 3`, `print("Number:", 5)` is equivalent to `print("Number:", sum([2, 3])`. Take the following snippet for example:

```py
def number():
    return 5

print("Number:", number())

print("Number:", 5)
```

Both print statements would create the same output since the method called `number()` would simply be evaluated to the value `5` before the print statement is called. If you were to modify the `number` method to print additional values you would see them output as you describe:

```
def number():
    print("number method called...")
    return 5

print("Number:", number())
```

In this case you would see two lines printed to the console:

```
number method called...
Number: 5
```